# SO2_column_number_density has negative value

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-5p, air-quality

The description of SO2_column_number_density in Sentinel-5P NRTI SO2: Near Real-Time Sulfur Dioxide says that "SO2 vertical column density at ground level, calculated using the DOAS technique" and the value's interval is from -48 to 0.8 mol/m^2. I do want to know if it is possible that mol has negative value since it represents matter? How do I interpret the negative value?

Answer (score 0):

These issues are expressly discussed in the product documentation.
https://sentinel.esa.int/documents/247904/0/Sentinel-5P-Sulphur-Dioxide-Readme.pdf/5cf0dcc7-d894-4169-a0ae-a347ad99b17d

**Negative Vertical Column Density values**

Because of noise on the data, negative vertical column values are often observed in particular over
clean regions or for low SO2 emissions. It is recommended not to filter these values except for outliers,
i.e. for vertical columns lower than -0.001 mol. m-2

**Contamination of reference sector by volcanic eruption (solved in version 02.01.03)**

Occasionally, the reference spectrum can also be contaminated by volcanic SO2 if a volcanic plume is
being transported in the geographical region used to select reference spectra (the equatorial Pacific).
This leads to a negative bias on SO2 which is not compensated immediately by BG. Since version
02.01.03, another zone is selected in case the reference sector is contaminated by a volcanic eruption.